# Ansible how to access list of dictionaries when using with_together

Tags: aws-lambda, ansible, amazon-sns

I am trying to create an ansible playbook which will allow me to create an AWS Lambda in a number of regions, and for each Lambda also register an SNS with the Lambda as a trigger. (If I am misunderstanding the process please feel free to point out my mistake, I am not 100% what I am doing is correct)

I have the following code in Ansible:

```
      lambda:
        name: "{{ item[0] }}"
        state: present
        s3_bucket: "my-devops-lambdas-{{ item[1] }}"
        s3_key: "{{ item[0] }}.zip"
        runtime: python3.6
        role: arn:aws:iam::****:role/devops-lambdas
        handler: lambda.lambda_handler
        region: "{{ item[1] }}"
      register: lambda_config
      with_items:
        - "{{ projects_to_build.stdout | from_json }}"

    - name: Register SNS
      sns_topic:
        name: "{{ item.0[2] }}"
        region: "{{ item.0[0] }}"
        subscriptions:
          - protocol: LAMBDA
          - endpoint: "{{ item.1.configuration.function_arn }}"
      with_together:
        - "{{ projects_to_build.stdout | from_json }}"
        - "{{ lambda_config.results }}"
```

My `projects_to_build` looks like this:

```
    "failed": false, 
    "projects_to_build.stdout": [
        [
            "cloudwatch-to-slack", 
            "eu-west-2", 
            "arn:aws:sns:eu-west-2:****:slack_devops"
        ], 
        [
            "cloudwatch-to-slack", 
            "eu-west-1", 
            "arn:aws:sns:eu-west-1:****:slack_devops"
        ]
    ]
}
```

I think I should be using `with_subelements` in order to access the items within my `lambda_config` results, but I don't see how I can use that at the same time as `with_together`.

I would post the `lambda_config` here, but it is huge, the format of the config is similar to [this](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/lambda_module.html) except that because I have multiple lambdas being created the results are a dictionary with `results` being a list of the results for each lambda created.

I am using Ansible 2.6, so I can use the new loops method instead of with_together, but so far I have been unable to find any way that will work.

I get this error when I try to run as is:

```
TASK [Register SNS] ************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'ansible.utils.unsafe_proxy.AnsibleUnsafeText object' has no attribute 'configuration'\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Global/devops-lambdas/aws/shared/deploy-devops-lambdas.yml': line 46, column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n    - name: Register SNS\n      ^ here\n"}
    to retry, use: --limit @/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Global/devops-lambdas/aws/shared/deploy-devops-lambdas.retry
```

I have tried a number of other solutions, one I thought might work was to use:

```
      with_together:
        - "{{ projects_to_build.stdout | from_json }}"
        - "{{ lambda_config.results | list }}"
```

That results in the same error. How do I iterate through the list of lambda results contained within `lambda_config.results`?

====EDIT DEBUG====

I already had a debug step, and it does appear as I was expecting @larsks it hasn't helped me so far, maybe it can help you?

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "failed": false, 
    "lambda_config": {
        "changed": true, 
        "msg": "All items completed", 
        "results": [
            {
                "_ansible_ignore_errors": null, 
                "_ansible_item_result": true, 
                "_ansible_no_log": false, 
                "_ansible_parsed": true, 
                "changed": true, 
                "code": {
                    "location": "https://awslambda-eu-west-2-tasks.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/snapshots/****/cloudwatch-to-slack-cf94f4d9-fc73-495b-aff5-b6c619d38b28?versionId=kzf3OeHyAo1KAYF.WidtJch0730rckRa&X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEAYaCWV1LXdlc3QtMiJHMEUCIQCjBXJcZKqxWX%2FMuj0zrAWO2UMMVyY22sCB%2Fo4YM02yqgIgBXVv0h2efZNqtjOJuyJlUAU0ou6StJLTXiBQzn%2B5BY4q0gIILhABGgw0NzIwMzg4NjQxODgiDDWKUw4k946LccANVCqvAgv5WC7AbvV9IhdAd3kXXGIxTqnRYJsneoNXYgf3BC3tRAYxrq2D0u0iL7HAqGqL97L6IRneu4H5pDqHalSfgBvriSrI8hDpDLsNJ08d9pMFigOWM9HWpi0rCwkRRG7FSjNgT4oqqZwUEcQl7H36a53qAdFGUp60S6Y4nZxuOkg3jgiyx6fkyXy8MAWxk8A6AogKQc0uubhcIbJNMGLrF3uyoROONdXNVtbJzkIQOZdoXxDW%2BMOr%2BBuyOz8%2F6RZqyiS3FkKCRuhl5GFueSDIW1ZUjzw68aRi1%2BFoCkIjxvf5cvfxwkOYW0UculsbAzv82F1CA3foeKUpR%2FWzUl5HRKzzB7MuZNntwac7rPOSbDNgAvbAdRibbUUbETDnBm7BmMalx9V%2BMXeK%2BHNHuk2eQDDsnbDuBTrNAl6I1SKoiX0iU5lvWmm8yXpE8NEA98g%2F1xzbmGlMPAFDg3sX19zts5xK%2BcYuZ9NG1kfReW7lo7kDVCTvGIhZmF9%2B%2FK2mmo%2FIoTYY6v7WygsrgyG2QGaE%2B5BdljJ1Kpb05We1v877JJNxrwX%2BhyUH2iD8wJS4k2bMum%2FytT02YnX014kSW21V6UVqMYftmcZ%2BYAE%2BQWdxqYgJtry9ZJFEdwwYAkJ2wgvqoLtBK3aaVQRDYw0TXtOnATi5EVn%2FQobtNO%2BXVmqflcGdJrtlVapFqKqX17eJw6KvnRo9%2BeMQ5OAKMt6xVA1p%2F3uxxIhQuyB9b8maRMg3TWfiUs%2FpYhjHQI%2FDaz00dAllvQBvjR%2FFjAeP76%2BVQzpiBW1tLQTBqzJZ1aQqfOB7vV6KkqSok%2BndT1hFwRbFgf76AboKGfwWuVHh7g0aWtnzQ%2FFF%2Fmizcg%3D%3D&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20191113T150904Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=600&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAW3Z5VOU6FMHUHSL2%2F20191113%2Feu-west-2%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=eb46bba09f8496841d67f2b24a042b0a3467fae7adcf1149bb8ca1e269f1604e", 
                    "repository_type": "S3"
                }, 
                "configuration": {
                    "code_sha256": "LmvHp5ZwvJXHK4pvVFOQqjtW13izWo2Kv4sJ6l1j7XY=", 
                    "code_size": 12098675, 
                    "description": "", 
                    "function_arn": "arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-2:****:function:cloudwatch-to-slack:20", 
                    "function_name": "cloudwatch-to-slack", 
                    "handler": "lambda.lambda_handler", 
                    "last_modified": "2019-11-13T15:09:04.488+0000", 
                    "memory_size": 128, 
                    "revision_id": "cd9af309-a209-4630-897a-9ee5e7c164cb", 
                    "role": "arn:aws:iam::****:role/devops-lambdas", 
                    "runtime": "python3.6", 
                    "timeout": 3, 
                    "tracing_config": {
                        "mode": "PassThrough"
                    }, 
                    "version": "20"
                }, 
                "failed": false, 
                "invocation": {
                    "module_args": {
                        "aws_access_key": null, 
                        "aws_secret_key": null, 
                        "dead_letter_arn": null, 
                        "description": "", 
                        "ec2_url": null, 
                        "environment_variables": null, 
                        "handler": "lambda.lambda_handler", 
                        "memory_size": 128, 
                        "name": "cloudwatch-to-slack", 
                        "profile": null, 
                        "region": "eu-west-2", 
                        "role": "arn:aws:iam::****:role/devops-lambdas", 
                        "runtime": "python3.6", 
                        "s3_bucket": "my-devops-lambdas-eu-west-2", 
                        "s3_key": "cloudwatch-to-slack.zip", 
                        "s3_object_version": null, 
                        "security_token": null, 
                        "state": "present", 
                        "tags": null, 
                        "timeout": 3, 
                        "validate_certs": true, 
                        "vpc_security_group_ids": null, 
                        "vpc_subnet_ids": null, 
                        "zip_file": null
                    }
                }, 
                "item": [
                    "cloudwatch-to-slack", 
                    "eu-west-2", 
                    "arn:aws:sns:eu-west-2:****:slack_devops"
                ], 
                "response_metadata": {
                    "http_headers": {
                        "connection": "keep-alive", 
                        "content-length": "2451", 
                        "content-type": "application/json", 
                        "date": "Wed, 13 Nov 2019 15:09:04 GMT", 
                        "x-amzn-requestid": "deb5eab6-39d8-451c-851a-096da70056ee"
                    }, 
                    "http_status_code": 200, 
                    "request_id": "deb5eab6-39d8-451c-851a-096da70056ee", 
                    "retry_attempts": 0
                }
            }, 
            {
                "_ansible_ignore_errors": null, 
                "_ansible_item_result": true, 
                "_ansible_no_log": false, 
                "_ansible_parsed": true, 
                "changed": true, 
                "code": {
                    "location": "https://awslambda-eu-west-1-tasks.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/snapshots/****/cloudwatch-to-slack-dad6d47a-b4d6-4d03-8300-e9a47e652415?versionId=510url5wG1BMpTNk047YFeKYDpPwH9HH&X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEAYaCWV1LXdlc3QtMSJGMEQCIBXrZqSZ4rvZKX27JqGrh2I1lUXqcYbFEu65TsYYaD7yAiBACK9qTPJFttLMbhNglvrKI%2F80hGO2hRn2wlRHIcY2hSrRAgguEAEaDDk1NDM2OTA4MjUxMSIMEQgZtz75PVoFjg%2FSKq4CYnr%2BXPNGag8Y5s3mncAQJbftOPYRffNPV1tsJcN%2BEYANTgKaiNBv%2FkOLpKLNaTuTtPZVa%2F6PO20zsD6GBK%2BeQL0craOJhNmawU50vpRlGIWyQKHhPyGbidr3%2FjE6eN%2B9TfHmrp2HyxfOy8L8wMfa%2BuuRfSsVlE3qdu57zhXCOClb2HFcbDrOLCS%2BFyDuFAFxDmeZ8wLlOv%2BiSIJvwX0LcXNHXmRhpKbqQ%2F8tsOLkwnfW80ri5PVvO9f9%2FOq5spEC8PWNbaSp5TEsnzPodM14PD1E4TIDn1UogDueIUvZ2nJRHCGw4P7glzI78e1NcMPT5eJAr2zT50V3nkT%2FlKgX5M7tnFhnW9IXdHxTIOIwjtVun4jUCSFh5897wPTb39tGLl163sCuM8FjxMKC5Lowy52w7gU6zwIOVYWYv%2B02dlMT5TV0mOCHxXnGx4DEORRcYJyVAHNVLK0%2BLaFcNWcS6YLKWNnSwBVc0uL2agamVB%2FU1bOBNBePTtT71icqxaMBfgOeztW%2BdH9Z%2BtH9e49QBCR4RqtuWd%2BdqW2oSwU78qiHYDbD0C6I9ncp546Q96BkEy%2FGTdSxLHr6dK%2BzGC5B39z6Vm8U4vEr22%2B8q44PuRx6dvIAE36VoiE9yEVJ4lAePb924VHEgnSxFEWUxQwNeoRcydU2%2BD1X34%2FForAo8upzZDOJl47eSv5SsQltGi0FsTkvhCld9aYT3EKWywXp8AJUalWSONtFXToh5xCc%2F3chuho5MkssdShdXi3wpX9epgRP0rYFSOh0VoeTZ6PauQ2B8dzK58adkwvTXuefYzNk6Yei%2Bei%2B8Wn0%2FIbU8k5L0YAiT%2FMrObPjtbcVmFRY%2FWYDlc8G7g%3D%3D&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20191113T150906Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=600&X-Amz-Credential=ASIA54NGUQSH3ABZBRID%2F20191113%2Feu-west-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=8cb09d879f729f19d01c11fc2deb1d49a6e409f2284878d879e6f197ad73f67d", 
                    "repository_type": "S3"
                }, 
                "configuration": {
                    "code_sha256": "cW3LqsTkdXwBacHpRvgfruZ7svIhy7gvB80keZqVpjw=", 
                    "code_size": 12100273, 
                    "description": "", 
                    "function_arn": "arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:****:function:cloudwatch-to-slack:21", 
                    "function_name": "cloudwatch-to-slack", 
                    "handler": "lambda.lambda_handler", 
                    "last_modified": "2019-11-13T15:09:05.780+0000", 
                    "memory_size": 128, 
                    "revision_id": "e48a6926-fd7c-44f8-9e1f-3f24e0fc82fb", 
                    "role": "arn:aws:iam::****:role/devops-lambdas", 
                    "runtime": "python3.6", 
                    "timeout": 3, 
                    "tracing_config": {
                        "mode": "PassThrough"
                    }, 
                    "version": "21"
                }, 
                "failed": false, 
                "invocation": {
                    "module_args": {
                        "aws_access_key": null, 
                        "aws_secret_key": null, 
                        "dead_letter_arn": null, 
                        "description": "", 
                        "ec2_url": null, 
                        "environment_variables": null, 
                        "handler": "lambda.lambda_handler", 
                        "memory_size": 128, 
                        "name": "cloudwatch-to-slack", 
                        "profile": null, 
                        "region": "eu-west-1", 
                        "role": "arn:aws:iam::****:role/devops-lambdas", 
                        "runtime": "python3.6", 
                        "s3_bucket": "my-devops-lambdas-eu-west-1", 
                        "s3_key": "cloudwatch-to-slack.zip", 
                        "s3_object_version": null, 
                        "security_token": null, 
                        "state": "present", 
                        "tags": null, 
                        "timeout": 3, 
                        "validate_certs": true, 
                        "vpc_security_group_ids": null, 
                        "vpc_subnet_ids": null, 
                        "zip_file": null
                    }
                }, 
                "item": [
                    "cloudwatch-to-slack", 
                    "eu-west-1", 
                    "arn:aws:sns:eu-west-1:****:slack_devops"
                ], 
                "response_metadata": {
                    "http_headers": {
                        "connection": "keep-alive", 
                        "content-length": "2453", 
                        "content-type": "application/json", 
                        "date": "Wed, 13 Nov 2019 15:09:06 GMT", 
                        "x-amzn-requestid": "78704b46-7dce-49c1-961e-cb8882088566"
                    }, 
                    "http_status_code": 200, 
                    "request_id": "78704b46-7dce-49c1-961e-cb8882088566", 
                    "retry_attempts": 0
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the problem with your existing "Register SNS" task?

Comment: It can't find the key "configuration" as it is nested within a list, I need to use one of the items in lambda_config.results for each "Register SNS" together with one of the projects to build

Comment: Someone here just took a look at it with me and told me that it should work, maybe it's a bug :( I added the error message to my question @larsks

Comment: That error is telling you that `item.1` is a string, not a dictionary. I would start by adding a debug task so that you can verify that `item` in your looping task looks they way you think it does.